# Android LinearLayout Gone don't update automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have a form that it could be submitted and send the data to an API, so when I receive the callback of request done I would like to hide the form and show a view of thanks.
This is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thank_you_layout_rate"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_circle_green_800_48dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/thank_you_for_rating"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
            android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/form_rating"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/rate_our_app"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
            android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingbar_rate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:isIndicator="false"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="4"
            android:stepSize="1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />


        <EditText
            android:hint="@string/rate_our_app"
            android:id="@+id/comment_rate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
            android:textColor="@color/DarkBlue"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_rate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@color/DecathlonBlue"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
            android:textColor="@color/LightGrey"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my fragment :

```
class RateFragment : Fragment(), RateFragmentListener {

    private lateinit var mLoginManager: LoginManager
    private lateinit var loadingDialog: LoadingDialog
    private lateinit var ratePresenter: RatePresenter
    private lateinit var mView: View

    private lateinit var rateNotAllowed: LinearLayout
    private lateinit var formRating: LinearLayout

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(loginManager: LoginManager): Fragment {
            val currentFragment = RateFragment()
            currentFragment.mLoginManager = loginManager
            return currentFragment
        }
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        this.stopLoadingDialog()
        super.onResume()
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param inflater LayoutInflater
     * @param container ViewGroup?
     * @param savedInstanceState Bundle?
     * @return View?
     */
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rate_fragment, container, false)

        val saveButton = mView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.save_rate)
        val starBar = mView.findViewById<RatingBar>(R.id.ratingbar_rate)
        val commentRate = mView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.comment_rate)
        rateNotAllowed = mView.findViewById(R.id.thank_you_layout_rate)
        formRating = mView.findViewById(R.id.form_rating)

        loadingDialog = LoadingDialog(context!!)

        startLoadingDialog()

        initPresenter(activity as Activity, this)

        saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            this.startLoadingDialog()
            ratePresenter.sendRating(
                    commentRate.text.toString(),
                    starBar.rating
            )
        }

        return mView
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param activity Activity
     */
    private fun initPresenter(
            activity: Activity,
            rateFragment: RateFragment
    ) {
        ratePresenter = RatePresenter(activity, mLoginManager, rateFragment)
    }

    /**
     * Loading dialog, block the UI
     */
    override fun stopLoadingDialog() {
        loadingDialog.dismiss()
    }

    /**
     * Loading dialog, block de UI
     */
    override fun startLoadingDialog() {
        loadingDialog.show()
    }


    override fun rateSent() {
        stopLoadingDialog()
    }

    override fun rateError() {
        activity!!.toast("error on sending the rating")
        stopLoadingDialog()
    }

    override fun rateNotAllowed() {
        formRating.visibility = View.GONE
        rateNotAllowed.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

But the update of the view isn't done automatically only if I change the vie and come back to it ( there is an if inside the presenter that check if a note is sent or not ).

Thank you, regards

Comment: I don't see `rateNotAllowed()` method call. Where should it be called?

Comment: It will be called by a async tasck in background.. I'm shure it is called after the form was submitted.

Comment: If changing visibility is called in async task, it can throw exception (as any other UI operation). Is there any `try-catch` in your async task to check it?

Comment: Yes there is a try catch, but the async task doesn't generate errors, only the view is not updated.